# Is there any source in nlp to summarize the required text

Tags: python-3.x, nlp

Create a custom model that allows to extract the required text from certain contents.

```
For Eg: My text is like:

text =  Encounter: URONAV/BX ACTIVE PROBLEMS • Benign prostatic hyperplasia with lower urinary tract symp REASON FOR VISIT Referred by. Elevated PSA. HISTORY OF PRESENT ILLNESS JAMES EVERING is an 81 year old male. 81 yo w rising PSA, suspicious lesion noted on Prostate MRI, here for UroNav biopsy. Patient of Dr Gary Leach. • Medication list reviewed. CURRENT MEDICATION • AmLODIPine Besylate 5 MG Tablet 90 days, 0 refills • Aspirin 81 MG Tablet 0 days, 0 refills • Simvastatin 20 MG Tablet 90 days, 0 refills PREVIOUS THERAPY • History of education and instructions; • History of instructions for patient; • History of education and counseling SOCIAL HISTORY Behavioral: No tobacco use and smoking status: Never smoker. ALLERGIES • Sulfa Drugs • Tetracyclines FAMILY HISTORY Family medical history was unknown Paternal: No chronic renal failure No Renal Calculus No prostate cancer No kidney cancer.

Solution: 1) ACTIVE PROBLEMS • Benign prostatic hyperplasia with lower urinary tract symp
2) CURRENT MEDICATION • AmLODIPine Besylate 5 MG Tablet 90 days, 0 refills • Aspirin 81 MG Tablet 0 days, 0 refills • Simvastatin 20 MG Tablet 90 days, 0 refills
3)HISTORY OF PRESENT ILLNESS JAMES EVERING is an 81 year old male. 81 yo w rising PSA,
```

Is there any source in nlp to create custom model that summarize required text from contents. Kindly suggest any ideas

Comment: As this sits, this is not a great question for this site as recommendation of products is typically frowned on. That said, NLTK is a popular python library for NLP. If you are looking for help with specific code questions, I recommend you try something and then ask a specific coding questions based on where you get. Note, it will be important to include the *text* version of you code.

Comment: I dont require any coding help. I just require any idea or any source from various sites which is able to create summary based on extracting the required text. Most of the website they do extractive and abstractive summary by shortening the paragraph and cleaning the text. Is there any source that help to identify creating custom summary to get required text

Comment: The most straightforward method is to tokenize each sentence then evaluate a scoring of each sentence and retain the best ones. An alternative might be to do something with markov chains but that can lead to nonsense.